# Reading XML structure using dynamic features

Tags: c#, xml, dynamic, xml-parsing, linq-to-xml

Consider I have an XML file which is loaded into an `XElement` or something like it. One way of reaching the tag values is to use `Element()` method.

Is there any way to facilitate this using dynamic objects. For example I want to replace

```
var val = xelement.Element("Name").Value
```

with

```
var dyn = (dynamic)xelement;
var val = dyn.Name;
```

It's a good idea to have nested properties too. For example:

```
var val = dyn.Person.Name;
```

Or even better:

```
var val = dyn.Children.Where(c=>c.Name == "Mehran").FirstOrDefault().Age;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe I've answered your question in the form of a blog post which you can read at http://blog.waseem-sabjee.com/2014/09/14/how-to-convert-an-xml-document-to-a-dynamic-object-in-net/

the blog post also contains a download link to a working solution.

here's some implementation code for you to look at:
(note that the ToDynamicList method is an extension method, the code for it is available on my blog.)

```
            XElement doc = XElement.Load(reader);

            // using our ToDynamicList (Extenion Method)
            var people = doc.ToDynamicList();

            // loop through each person
            foreach (dynamic person in people.Where(X => X.Name == "Waseem"))
            {
                Console.WriteLine("id:\t" + person.Id);
                Console.WriteLine("Name:\t" + person.Name);
                Console.WriteLine("Age:\t" + person.Age);
                Console.WriteLine("----------------------------------");
                try
                {
                    // loop through children, if any
                    foreach(dynamic child in person.Children)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("\tid:\t" + child.Id);
                        Console.WriteLine("\tName:\t" + child.Name);
                        Console.WriteLine("\tAge:\t" + child.Age);
                    }
                    Console.WriteLine("----------------------------------");
                }
                catch(Exception ex)
                {
                }
            }

        }
```